# Как добавить ссылку на сборку в Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

В Visual Studio 2010 появился фильтр сборок по версии .NET.

У меня есть приложение, которое пишется под версию 3.5 SP1. Но MapXtreme написан под 2-й .NET. Чтобы добавить в проект ссылку на MapXtreme, приходится выделывать такие пляски с бубном:

- Добавить в решение проект, собираемый под 2-й .NET
- Добавить туда ссылку на MapXtreme
- Скопировать созданную ссылку и вставить её в нужный проект.

Это как-нибудь можно сделать по-человечески?

Comment: Никакого фильтра в студии нет. Ссылка отлично добавляется через кнопку browse в стандартном диалоге.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два способа в зависимости от того, какие библиотеки тебе надо добавить.

1. Если надо добавить ссылку на сборку, которая есть в стандартной поставке Visual Studio, то в начале кода просто допиши `using <название сборки>`.
2. Если надо добавить внешнюю ссылку, то в дереве проекта (обозреватель решений) в разделе "Ссылки" нажми правой кнопкой и выбери пункт "Добавить ссылку" и там выбираешь то, что надо.

Comment: В Visual Studio в описанном сценарии именно это не работает.